# Speed up dividing date intervals by minutes in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to divide some date intervals by minutes. (For example, 2012-01-01 10:00 - 2012-01-01 10:00 interval should be divided into 2012-01-01 10:01, 2012-01-01 10:02, ... 2012-01-01 10:10).
For example, there is a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EventEnd] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

This table is filled like

```
DECLARE @i integer = 0;
DECLARE @initial_date datetime = '2012-01-01';

WHILE @i < 50000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Events] (EventStart, EventEnd, Amount) VALUES (DATEADD(MINUTE, 10*@i, @initial_date), DATEADD(MINUTE, 10*(@i + 1), @initial_date), @i);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

As a result we have many 10 minutes intervals.

To divide it by minutes I use the following recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime = '2012-01-01';
DECLARE @end_date datetime = '2013-01-02';


WITH Date_Ranges (StatDate, Amount, IntervalStart, CurrentMinute) AS (
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, 0,  ev.EventStart) AS StatDate, ev.Amount, ev.EventStart AS IntervalStart, 1 AS CurrentMinute
  FROM [Events] ev
  WHERE ev.EventStart BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, CurrentMinute, ev.EventStart), ev.Amount, ev.EventStart AS IntervalStart, CurrentMinute + 1
  FROM [Events] ev
  INNER JOIN Date_Ranges ranges ON (ranges.IntervalStart = ev.EventStart AND 
    ranges.StatDate >= ev.EventStart AND 
    ranges.StatDate < ev.EventEnd)
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, CurrentMinute, ev.EventStart) BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date AND
        ev.EventStart BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
) 

SELECT *
FROM Date_Ranges --ORDER BY StatDate
```

The main problem is too slow execution of this recursive CTE on a large data amount.

So, how can I speed up this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns all 550,000 rows in roughly 1/2 the time of the recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime = '2012-01-01'; 
DECLARE @end_date datetime = '2013-01-02';

SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, x.number, ev.EventStart) AS StartDate, 
        ev.Amount, 
        ev.EventStart as IntervalStart, 
        x.number as CurrentMinute
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
CROSS JOIN Events ev
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ev.EventStart, ev.EventEnd)
AND     ev.EventStart BETWEEN @start_date and @end_date
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I need. It is faster than recursive CTE in many times on my real data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest set of buckets will be a table. Create a table of 10-minute buckets, populate it, then join on it. This completely avoids recursion, and leverages one of the things a SQL dbms is really good at--joins.

10 years of 10-minute buckets is only a half million rows.

Recursion in a CTE is a Good Thing when you're dealing with something like a bill of materials. But it's not always a suitable substitute for a table.

---

I created a table of 10-minute buckets covering 10 years. (That's about 4 megabytes of data.  I didn't try to calculate how much disk indexes and row overhead took.) Then I created a table of test data containing 20 million random timestamps, all within the same 10 years as the table of buckets.

After adding indexes appropriate to the problem, the test system "buckets" one random day's data in about 100ms. (PostgreSQL dbms without tuning, running on a 5-year-old Dell computer with 1 gig of RAM. I'm on a Linux system here, so I couldn't test SQL Server itself. I'd expect similar results, though.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Sql Express and disk space is critical for mee too :)

Comment: 10 years of 1-minute buckets is less than 45 megabytes for data.

Comment: Yes, I do understand. This example is simplified. Real amount of data is much more.

Comment: You need more than 10 years of 1-minute buckets?

Comment: Sorry, I understood you incorrectly. After your edit it has become more clear for me. You decision is great.

Comment: What is the best way to build index on this "buckets" table? I tried to use nonclustered and clustered. There were the sampe results. It seems to be that Sql Server cannot handle datetime as unique and appends hidden id to build clustered index.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't really support clustered indexes, so mine are unclustered. I'll post the table structure by editing my answer.